# Python. Извлечь «тройки» дата – глагол – персона (упомянутые в одном предложении)

Tags: python, nlp, natasha

Входные данные:

> Петр I родился 30 мая 1672 года.
> В детстве он получил домашнее образование, с юных лет знал немецкий язык, затем изучал голландский, английский и французский языки.
> С помощью дворцовых мастеров освоил много ремесел...

Выходные данные: ['Петр', 'родился'] [Match(start=15, stop=31, fact=Date(year=1672, month=5, day=30))]
['он', 'получил', 'знал'] []
['освоил'] []

UPD:
Разбил по root и nsubj,также добавил даты, но теперь встает вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы выводило только root+nsubj+дата

```
!pip install natasha
# подключаем библиотеку
from natasha import (
Segmenter,
MorphVocab,

NewsEmbedding,
NewsMorphTagger,
NewsSyntaxParser,
NewsNERTagger,

PER,
LOC,

NamesExtractor,
MoneyExtractor,
AddrExtractor,
DatesExtractor,

Doc
)

segmenter = Segmenter()
morph_vocab = MorphVocab()

emb = NewsEmbedding()
morph_tagger = NewsMorphTagger(emb)
syntax_parser = NewsSyntaxParser(emb)
ner_tagger = NewsNERTagger(emb)

names_extractor = NamesExtractor(morph_vocab)
dates_extractor = DatesExtractor(morph_vocab)
money_extractor = MoneyExtractor(morph_vocab)
addr_extractor = AddrExtractor(morph_vocab)

text = '''Петр I родился 30 мая 1672 года. 
В детстве он получил домашнее образование, с юных лет знал немецкий язык, затем изучал голландский, английский и французский языки. 
С помощью дворцовых мастеров освоил много ремесел...'''

doc = Doc(text)
doc.segment(segmenter)
doc.tag_morph(morph_tagger)
doc.parse_syntax(syntax_parser)
doc.parse_syntax(syntax_parser)
doc.tag_ner(ner_tagger)

morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
dates_extractor = DatesExtractor(morph_vocab)
for i in range (len(doc.sents)):
  new_numbers = []
  for j in range (len(doc.sents[i].tokens)):
    doc.sents[i].tokens[j].lemmatize(morph_vocab)
    list(dates_extractor(doc.sents[i].text))
    if ((doc.sents[i].tokens[j].rel == 'root') or (doc.sents[i].tokens[j].rel == 'nsubj')):
      new_numbers.append(doc.sents[i].tokens[j].text)
  print(new_numbers,list(dates_extractor(doc.sents[i].text)))
```

Comment: а что именно не получается? Приложите результат который есть и который вам нужно. Не забывайте что есть минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Всего доброго!

Comment: И добавьте все нужные импорты и инициализации, чтобы можно было ваш код взять и покрутить, а не соображать ещё, что тут нужно импортировать.

Comment: Исправился, извиняюсь

Comment: Потеряли кусок строки после `or`, теперь код не компилируется

Comment: Ну даты нужно через `dates_extractor` искать, а вы его даже и не применяете

Comment: "Упомянутые в одном предложении" - значит по отдельным предложениям нужно работать, а вы сразу весь текст разбираете. В остальном да, если лишний последний `or` выкинуть, то почти всё у вас есть что нужно, если добавить экстрактор дат. Самому из токенов дату собрать думаю сложновато будет, лучше экстрактором.

Comment: Тогда таким образом у меня будет выводить не связанные тройки, к примеру:
Текст : Александр и Петр родились в одно время - дата
Вывод: Александр Петр родились дата
а требуется отделить, то есть Александр родился дата

Comment: В каком смысле не связанные? Если вы работаете с предложением, то смотрите: есть ли в предложении все три нужных элемента. Если есть - выводите. Кончилось предложение - все списки и прочие свои данные обнуляете. Начинаете следующее предложение "с чистого листа" обрабатывать. Если вам нужен порядок, в котором элементы идут, то он есть в этих структурах - там записано с какой позиции элемент нашёлся, вы просто этой информацией не пользуетесь. Если надо порядок - пользуйтесь этой информацией, сортируйте элементы.

Comment: Привожу пример
Входные:Петр I – младший сын царя Алексея Михайловича от второго брака с Натальей Нарышкиной – родился 30 мая 1672 года.
Выходные:['Петр I', 'Алексея Михайловича', 'Натальей Нарышкиной'] ['родился'] [Match(start=95, stop=111, fact=Date(year=1672, month=5, day=30))]
А нужно: Петр I родился дата

Comment: Вы точку видите? Точка делит предложения. Не только точка, но для начала пойдёт. Разбейте текст на предложения и работайте с предложениями. Не знаю есть ли в Наташе для этого инструмент, для начала можно регулярным выражением разбить или просто даже `split('.')`

Comment: А вы видите что я написал? Одно предложение имеет несколько персоналей и выводит их все, а мне нужно их связать, Кто? - Петр, не Алексей или еще кто-то , а Петр; Что сделал? - родился, опять же не АЛексей, а кто? Петр; Когда родился? 1672

Comment: А, прошу прощения, я смотрел на примеры из вопроса, вы уже другие примеры в комментариях пишете. Обновляйте тогда вопрос, если примеры уже другие, а то я не знаю, куда смотреть. Можно брать только первую персоналию, но вообще это более глубокий анализатор нужен, который может связывать части предложения между собой. Тут то мы можем взять первую персоналию просто, но если бы предложение было построено наоборот, например "Младший сын царя Алексея Михайловича Петр I...", то такой метод уже не сработал бы. Хотя тут можно было бы по падежам попытаться различить. `NLP` вообще тема не тривиальная.

Comment: До персоналий еще видимо далеко, сейчас хочу выяснить как выводить только глагол+субъект+дата, а не либо то,либо другое, почему-то меняя or на and выводит только дату